# Is there any way to make the input from a scanner into an interface?

Tags: java

I am trying to take the input from a user and make it into an interface. Is there any way for me to do that directly from the scanner input? I don't really know how else I would do it. Thanks for the help. My code is

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

SetInterface target = sc.nextLine();
```

Is there any way for me to make this string input equal to an interface?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by _I am trying to take the input from a user and make it into an interface_?

Comment: I have an interface. And I want the interface to equal the input entered by the user. But I am not sure how to do that and want to know if there even is a way for me to do that

Comment: What do you mean by _interface_? Can you provide an example?

Comment: What is that SetInterface?

Comment: Unless `SetInterface extends String`, please explain your [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) **in detail**

Comment: String cannot be extended as it is a final class.

Comment: @Samurai - Huh, learned something new today - too late to edit

Answer (score 0):

You can never directly equal a Scanner input with an Interface defined by you.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. You can't assign a `String` to an `interface` ever.

```
interface SetInterface {
    void doSomething(String s);
}

SetInterface target = "";
```

Compile error

`incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to SetInterface`